# how to correct syntax after angular update

Tags: javascript, angularjs, syntax-error

I want to upgrade to the lasted stable angular branch 1.4.7. I am coming from 1.2.13.
there is a angular-leaflet-directive in my project that was customized for the application. I am trying to figure out how to change the syntax in a function so it does not throw a error. 
console messages

```
Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '.50465' is an unexpected token at column 8 of the expression [markers.50465] starting at [.50465].
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.7/$parse/syntax?p0=.50465&p1=is%20an%20unexpected%20token&p2=8&p3=markers.50465&p4=.50465
at angular.js:68
at Object.AST.throwError (angular.js:13057)
at Object.AST.ast (angular.js:12827)
at Object.ASTCompiler.compile (angular.js:13276)
at Parser.parse (angular.js:14146)
at $parse (angular.js:14248)
at Scope.$watch (angular.js:15412)
at createMarker (angular-leaflet-directive.js:1496)
at Object.fn (angular-leaflet-directive.js:1158)
at Scope.$digest (angular.js:15826)(anonymous function) @    angular.js:12477(anonymous function) @ angular.js:9246Scope.$digest @  angular.js:15844Scope.$apply @ angular.js:16097done @ angular.js:10546completeRequest @ angular.js:10744requestLoaded @ angular.js:10685
```

function
error is at 'markers.'

```
   // add new markers
                for (var new_name in newMarkers) {
                    if (markers[new_name] === undefined) {
                        var newMarker = createMarker('markers.' + new_name, $scope.markers[new_name], map);
                        if (newMarker !== null) {
                            markers[new_name] = newMarker;
                        }
                    }
                }
```

line 1496 starts here.

```
  var clearWatch = $scope.$watch(scope_watch_name, function (data, old_data) {
                if (!data) {
                    marker.closePopup();
                    // There is no easy way to know if a marker is added to a layer, so we search for it
                    // if there are overlays
                    if (layers !== undefined && layers !== null) {
                        if (layers.overlays !== undefined) {
                            for (var key in layers.overlays) {
                                if (layers.overlays[key] instanceof L.LayerGroup) {
                                    if (layers.overlays[key].hasLayer(marker)) {
                                        layers.overlays[key].removeLayer(marker);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    map.removeLayer(marker);
                    clearWatch();
                    return;
                }

                if (old_data) {

                    //TODO Check for layers !== null
                    //TODO Check for layers.overlays !== null !== undefined
                    // It is possible the the layer has been removed or the layer marker does not exist

                    // Update the layer group if present or move it to the map if not
                    if (data.layer === undefined || data.layer === null || typeof data.layer !== 'string') {
                        // There is no layer information, we move the marker to the map if it was in a layer group
                        if (old_data.layer !== undefined && old_data.layer !== null && typeof old_data.layer === 'string') {
                            // Remove from the layer group that is supposed to be
                            if (layers.overlays[old_data.layer] !== undefined) {
                                if (layers.overlays[old_data.layer].hasLayer(marker)) {
                                    layers.overlays[old_data.layer].removeLayer(marker);
                                    // If the marker had a popup we close it because we do not know if the popup in on the map
                                    // or on the layer group. This is ineficient, but as we can't check if the popup is opened
                                    // in Leaflet we can't determine if it has to be open in the new layer. So removing the
                                    // layer group of a marker always closes the popup.
                                    // TODO: Improve popup behaviour when removing a marker from a layer group
                                    marker.closePopup();
                                }
                            }
                            // Test if it is not on the map and add it
                            if (!map.hasLayer(marker)) {
                                map.addLayer(marker);
                            }
                        }
                    } else if (old_data.layer === undefined || old_data.layer === null || old_data.layer !== data.layer) {
                        // If it was on a layer group we have to remove it
                        if (typeof old_data.layer === 'string') {
                            if (layers.overlays[old_data.layer] !== undefined) {
                                if (layers.overlays[old_data.layer].hasLayer(marker)) {
                                    layers.overlays[old_data.layer].removeLayer(marker);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        // If the marker had a popup we close it because we do not know how the new layer
                        // will be. This is ineficient, but as we can't check if the opoup is opened in Leaflet
                        // we can't determine if it has to be open in the new layer. So changing the layer group
                        // of a marker always closes the popup.
                        // TODO: Improve popup behaviour when changing a marker from a layer group
                        marker.closePopup();
                        // Remove it from the map in case the new layer is hidden or there is an error in the new layer
                        if (map.hasLayer(marker)) {
                            map.removeLayer(marker);
                        }
                        // The data.layer is defined so we add the marker to the layer if it is different from the old data
                        if (layers.overlays[data.layer] !== undefined) {
                            // Is a group layer?
                            var layerGroup = layers.overlays[data.layer];
                            if (layerGroup instanceof L.LayerGroup) {
                                // The marker goes to a correct layer group, so first of all we add it
                                layerGroup.addLayer(marker);
                                // The marker is automatically added to the map depending on the visibility
                                // of the layer, so we only have to open the popup if the marker is in the map
                                if (map.hasLayer(marker)) {
                                    if (data.focus === true) {
                                        marker.openPopup();
                                    }
                                }
                            } else {
                                $log.error('[AngularJS - Leaflet] A marker can only be added to a layer of type "group"');
                            }
                        } else {
                            $log.error('[AngularJS - Leaflet] You must use a name of an existing layer');
                        }
                    } else {
                        // Never has to enter here...
                    }

                    // Update the draggable property
                    if (data.draggable === undefined || data.draggable === null || data.draggable !== true) {
                        // If there isn't or wasn't the draggable property or is false and previously true update the dragging
                        // the !== true prevents for not boolean values in the draggable property
                        if (old_data.draggable !== undefined && old_data.draggable !== null && old_data.draggable === true) {
                            if (marker.dragging) {
                                marker.dragging.disable();
                            }
                        }
                    } else if (old_data.draggable === undefined || old_data.draggable === null || old_data.draggable !== true) {
                        // The data.draggable property must be true so we update if there wasn't a previous value or it wasn't true
                        if (marker.dragging) {
                            marker.dragging.enable();
                        } else {
                            if (L.Handler.MarkerDrag) {
                                marker.dragging = new L.Handler.MarkerDrag(marker);
                                marker.options.draggable = true;
                                marker.dragging.enable();
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    if (data.zIndexOffset && data.zIndexOffset != old_data.zIndexOffset) {
                        marker.setZIndexOffset(data.zIndexOffset);
                    }

                    // Update the icon property
                    if (data.icon === undefined || data.icon === null || typeof data.icon !== 'object') {
                        // If there is no icon property or it's not an object
                        if (old_data.icon !== undefined && old_data.icon !== null && typeof old_data.icon === 'object') {
                            // If there was an icon before restore to the default
                            marker.setIcon(new LeafletIcon());
                            marker.closePopup();
                            marker.unbindPopup();
                            if (data.message !== undefined && data.message !== null && typeof data.message === 'string' && data.message !== "") {
                                marker.bindPopup(data.message, {
                                    autoPan: data.popupOptions ? (data.popupOptions.autoPan ? true : false) : true
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    } else if (old_data.icon === undefined || old_data.icon === null || typeof old_data.icon !== 'object') {
                        // The data.icon exists so we create a new icon if there wasn't an icon before
                        var dragA = false;
                        if (marker.dragging) {
                            dragA = marker.dragging.enabled();
                        }
                        if (Helpers.AwesomeMarkersPlugin.is(data.icon)) {
                            // This icon is a L.AwesomeMarkers.Icon so it is using the AwesomeMarker PlugIn
                            marker.setIcon(data.icon);
                            // As the new icon creates a new DOM object some elements, as drag, are reseted.
                        } else if (Helpers.Leaflet.DivIcon.is(data.icon) || Helpers.Leaflet.Icon.is(data.icon)) {
                            // This is a Leaflet.DivIcon or a Leaflet.Icon
                            marker.setIcon(data.icon);
                        } else {
                            // This icon is a icon set in the model trough options
                            marker.setIcon(new LeafletIcon(data.icon));
                        }
                        if (dragA) {
                            marker.dragging.enable();
                        }
                        marker.closePopup();
                        marker.unbindPopup();
                        if (data.message !== undefined && data.message !== null && typeof data.message === 'string' && data.message !== "") {
                            marker.bindPopup(data.message, {
                                autoPan: data.popupOptions ? (data.popupOptions.autoPan ? true : false) : true
                            });
                        }

                    } else {
                        if (Helpers.AwesomeMarkersPlugin.is(data.icon)) {
                            // This icon is a L.AwesomeMarkers.Icon so it is using the AwesomeMarker PlugIn
                            if (!Helpers.AwesomeMarkersPlugin.equal(data.icon, old_data.icon)) {
                                var dragD = false;
                                if (marker.dragging) {
                                    dragD = marker.dragging.enabled();
                                }
                                marker.setIcon(data.icon);
                                // As the new icon creates a new DOM object some elements, as drag, are reseted.
                                if (dragD) {
                                    marker.dragging.enable();
                                }
                                //TODO: Improve depending on anchorPopup
                                // metrostudy
                                marker.closePopup();
                                if (marker._popup && marker._popup._isOpen) {
                                    marker.unbindPopup();
                                }
                                if (data.message !== undefined && data.message !== null && typeof data.message === 'string' && data.message !== "") {
                                    marker.bindPopup(data.message, {
                                        autoPan: data.popupOptions ? (data.popupOptions.autoPan ? true : false) : true
                                    });
                                }
                            }
                        } else if (Helpers.Leaflet.DivIcon.is(data.icon)) {
                            // This is a Leaflet.DivIcon
                            if (!Helpers.Leaflet.DivIcon.equal(data.icon, old_data.icon)) {
                                var dragE = false;
                                if (marker.dragging) {
                                    dragE = marker.dragging.enabled();
                                }
                                marker.setIcon(data.icon);
                                // As the new icon creates a new DOM object some elements, as drag, are reseted.
                                if (dragE) {
                                    marker.dragging.enable();
                                }
                                //TODO: Improve depending on anchorPopup
                                marker.closePopup();
                                marker.unbindPopup();
                                if (data.message !== undefined && data.message !== null && typeof data.message === 'string' && data.message !== "") {
                                    marker.bindPopup(data.message, {
                                        autoPan: data.popupOptions ? (data.popupOptions.autoPan ? true : false) : true
                                    });
                                }
                            }
                        } else if (Helpers.Leaflet.Icon.is(data.icon)) {
                            // This is a Leaflet.DivIcon
                            if (!Helpers.Leaflet.Icon.equal(data.icon, old_data.icon)) {
                                var dragF = false;
                                if (marker.dragging) {
                                    dragF = marker.dragging.enabled();
                                }
                                marker.setIcon(data.icon);
                                // As the new icon creates a new DOM object some elements, as drag, are reseted.
                                if (dragF) {
                                    marker.dragging.enable();
                                }
                                //TODO: Improve depending on anchorPopup
                                // metrostudy
                                //marker.closePopup();
                                //marker.unbindPopup();
                                //if (data.message !== undefined && data.message !== null && typeof data.message === 'string' && data.message !== "") {
                                //    marker.bindPopup(data.message, {
                                //        autoPan: data.popupOptions ? (data.popupOptions.autoPan ? true : false) : true
                                //    });
                                //}
                            }
                        } else {
                            // This icon is an icon defined in the marker model through options
                            // There is an icon and there was an icon so if they are different we create a new icon
                            if (JSON.stringify(data.icon) !== JSON.stringify(old_data.icon)) {
                                var dragG = false;
                                if (marker.dragging) {
                                    dragG = marker.dragging.enabled();
                                }
                                marker.setIcon(new LeafletIcon(data.icon));
                                if (dragG) {
                                    marker.dragging.enable();
                                }
                                //TODO: Improve depending on anchorPopup
                                marker.closePopup();
                                marker.unbindPopup();
                                if (data.message !== undefined && data.message !== null && typeof data.message === 'string' && data.message !== "") {
                                    marker.bindPopup(data.message, {
                                        autoPan: data.popupOptions ? (data.popupOptions.autoPan ? true : false) : true
                                    });
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    // Update the Popup message property
                    if (data.message === undefined || data.message === null || typeof data.message !== 'string' || data.message === "") {
                        // There is no popup to show, so if it has previously existed it must be unbinded
                        if (old_data.message !== undefined && old_data.message !== null && typeof old_data.message === 'string' && old_data.message !== "") {
                            marker.closePopup();
                            marker.unbindPopup();
                        }
                    } else {
                        // There is some text in the popup, so we must show the text or update existing
                        if (old_data.message === undefined || old_data.message === null || typeof old_data.message !== 'string' || old_data.message === "") {
                            // There was no message before so we create it
                            marker.bindPopup(data.message, {
                                autoPan: data.popupOptions ? (data.popupOptions.autoPan ? true : false) : true
                            });
                        } else if (data.message !== old_data.message) {
                            // There was a different previous message so we update it
                            marker.setPopupContent(data.message);
                        }
                    }

                    // Update the focus property
                    if (data.focus && !old_data.focus) {
                        // The data.focus property must be true so we update if there wasn't a previous value or it wasn't true
                        marker.openPopup();
                    }

                    // Update the lat-lng property (always present in marker properties)
                    if (data.lat === undefined || data.lat === null || isNaN(data.lat) || typeof data.lat !== 'number' || data.lng === undefined || data.lng === null || isNaN(data.lng) || typeof data.lng !== 'number') {
                        $log.warn('There are problems with lat-lng data, please verify your marker model');
                        // Remove the marker from the layers and map if it is not valid
                        if (layers !== null) {
                            if (layers.overlays !== undefined && layers.overlays !== null) {
                                for (var olname in layers.overlays) {
                                    if (layers.overlays[olname] instanceof L.LayerGroup || Helpers.MarkerClusterPlugin.is(layers.overlays[olname])) {
                                        if (layers.overlays[olname].hasLayer(marker)) {
                                            layers.overlays[olname].removeLayer(marker);
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        map.removeLayer(marker);
                    } else {
                        var cur_latlng = marker.getLatLng();
                        // On dragend event, scope will be updated, which
                        // tirggers this watch expression. Then we call
                        // setLatLng and triggers move event on marker and
                        // causes digest already in progress error.
                        //
                        // This check is to make sure we don't trigger move
                        // event manually after dragend, which is redundant
                        // anyway. Because before dragend event fired, marker
                        // sate is already updated by leaflet.
                        if (cur_latlng.lat !== data.lat || cur_latlng.lng !== data.lng) {
                            // if the marker is in a clustermarker layer it has to be removed and added again to the layer
                            var isCluster = false;
                            if (data.layer !== undefined && data.layer !== null && typeof data.layer === 'string') {
                                if (Helpers.MarkerClusterPlugin.is(layers.overlays[data.layer])) {
                                    layers.overlays[data.layer].removeLayer(marker);
                                    isCluster = true;
                                }
                            }
                            marker.setLatLng([data.lat, data.lng]);
                            if (isCluster) {
                                layers.overlays[data.layer].addLayer(marker);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }, true);
```

Comment: see update. let me know what else i should post!

Comment: You need to access the marker via `markers[' + id + ']`. Number is not a valid Javascript identifier. If you need more specific advice, share the code where you construct `scope_watch_name`.

Comment: i pasted the entire script in the js file. i could not figure out where it is being defined. http://plnkr.co/edit/dmxX3vPnHiNQrKCwhUGu?p=catalogue

Comment: Try changing all `createMarker('markers.' + name, ` to `createMarker('markers[' + name + ']',` .

Comment: that did it! please put in answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to access array elements via *property dot notation*. This is not a valid construct and you need to use *bracket notation* - `[]`.

The problem comes from a watch expression being `markers.12345`, which is taken from `createMarker('markers.' + name, ...)`. So instead of that write `createMarker('markers[' + name + ']', ...)`.